# Calculating the cost of the electricity consumption

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

in Excel 2003, I use the following equations to calculate the cost of the electricity consumption.
I have to use different equations for different consumption slice situations.

The next figure shows the data used for consumption slices and the cost for each slice:

[image]

I put fixed values in cells and refer to them. 
For example:
 0.5 in cell A1
 0.82 in cell B1
 1 in cell C1

in October the consumption was 190 kwh,

I used the equation =((190*$A$1))+6

in December the consumption was 228 kwh,

I used the equation =((200*$A$1)+(28*$B$1))+11

in August the consumption was 370 kwh,

I used the equation =((200*$A$1)+(150*$B$1)+(20*$C$1))+15

How to use one equation in all the different consumption slice situations, instead of using different equations in different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use formula efficiently you need first to calculate "cost correction" which gives you the difference between calculating with constant price (e.g. `370*1`) vs based on price categories (e.g. `200*0.5 + 150*0.82 + 20*1`), this will be constant for each category.

The formula for it is:
`=-(Sheet1!$A3-1)*(Sheet1!$B3-B2)+D2`
*(place it from second category and fill it down, for first one it's 0)*

Then you can use `VLOOKUP` to calculate based on cost, added fee & correction:
`=Sheet1!$G2*VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$G2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$5,2,TRUE)+VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$G2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$5,3,TRUE)+VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$G2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$5,4,TRUE)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just could not figure out the formulae in D4 and D5 resulting in -127 and -387 respectively

Comment: Would you please show me the formulae in D4 and D5, because I have other consumption slice data to add; and I could not figure out how to calculate cost correction for them.

Comment: I tried the following formulae; are they correct? for D4: =-($A$4-1)*($B$4-$B$3)-($A$3-1)*($B$3-$B$2)+$D$2   and for D5:   =-($A$5-1)*($B$5-$B$4)-($A$4-1)*($B$4-$B$3)-($A$3-1)*($B$3-$B$2)+$A$2

Comment: What is the value of adding +$D$2, because its value is 0?

Comment: `+D2` is there to enable filling down the formula, you just need to fill it down for all rows. Please see updated picture

Comment: Thank you very much